# What license is the Ubuntu colour pallete?

Tags: application-development, license

I am developing some Chrome app and started using Ubuntu colours for it. The ones I found in the [Ubuntu Colour Palette](http://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette). I assume it's there and public so that app developers could create a consistent experience for Ubuntu users. What about apps that do not aim at Ubuntu users? Like in my case - a browser extension. Is it legal to use these colours wherever I want or will it be considered a violation of a trademark/brand use?

I searched for terms of use of the colours but couldn't find any. I just assume it is copyrighted as a part of a brand/trademark.

P.S. I am an Ubuntu user and, as I consider my self as a primary user for the extension, I wanted an Ubuntu-like experience for myself. However, I am going to publish it so that more people could benefit from it and that's where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 1):

You can't patent or copyright a color scheme, so Canonical has no rights to it.

Comment: As far as I know, colour scheme can be a part of a `trademark` which can be (and usually is) copyrighted.